# Error connecting DB with Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, database, codeigniter

I have seen the same problem a hundred times here. But for some reason, all those solutions don't work for me. I'm using `Ajax` to connect to the database through the controller and model. But the `Ajax` request returns error every time. I think the problem may be located in the database.php.

**Ajax:**

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '<?php echo site_url("Main/resultadosBusqueda")?>',
      success: function(result){
      alert('Success:'+result);
      },
      error: function(result){
          console.log( JSON.stringify(result, null, 2) );
      alert('Error:'+result);
      }
  });
```

**Controller:**

```
  public function resultadosBusqueda() {
       $this->load->model('Buscar_model');
       echo $this->Buscar_model->buscarCartas();
  }
```

**Model:**

```
class Buscar_model  extends CI_Model {
   public function __construct() {
          parent::__construct();
   }

   public function buscarCartas() {
      $this->db->select('Card');
      $this->db-> from('Cards');
      $query = $this->db->get(); 

      return $query -> result_array();
   }
}
```

**database.php**

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'  => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'database' => 'CardTrade',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: What error? ..  Are you sure the path that Ajax uses is set in the routes and is redirected within CI to the controller?

Comment: @Gamath please write down error

Comment: I have tried to return a string ('Hello, world, here is the model') , without db connection, and works right. It is when I call or do anything related to the db when it stops working. The log in the browser console does not give any useful information at all.

Comment: In your last comment is half of answer ("to return a string"). So `json_encode(echo $this->Buscar_model->buscarCartas())`.

Comment: @Gamath please follow this steps, on the right click mouse in web page open `inspect` and click to the `network`. If you can not find `Main/resultadosBusqueda` refresh page again but don't close `inspect`. And write error on your question.

Comment: @TeymurMardaliyerLennon The error that gives me is: " 500 Internal server error" The same as in the console log.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the `.ajax` options after `url: ...`

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Then in the controller the last line should be

```
echo json_encode($this->Buscar_model->buscarCartas());
```

May not be exactly what you expect but it might cure the error everytime problem.

Comment: I did as you say. But the .ajax still returns me the error.